# ROS Init Exception

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I wrote two nodes in python and get the following exception when I start the nodes.

Can somebody tell me whats the problem?

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/geometry/tf/src/tf/listener.py", line 238, in     run
    rospy.spin()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/client.py", line 98, in spin
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException("client code must call    rospy.init_node() first")
ROSInitException: client code must call rospy.init_node() first
```

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57671/ros-init-exception/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You did not call rospy.init_node before calling rospy.spin.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0